# PostGIS 2 st_intersection FROM-clause error

Tags: postgis, postgis-2.0

I'm trying to run this query in a PostGIS 2 database:

```
create TABLE data.agri_grc as select
id, code_00,
ST_Intersection(data.agri.geom,data.grc_bor.geom) as geom from
data.agri;
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "grc_bor"
LINE 3: ST_Intersection(data.agri.geom,data.grc_bor.geom) as geom fr...
```

What am I missing?

Comment: http://selectoid.wordpress.com/2008/11/14/a-look-at-st_intersects-st_overlaps-and-st_intersection/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Mapperz Link pointed me to the right direction.

The correct SQL query seems to be :

```
create table data.agri_grc as select
 a.id, 
 a.code_00,
 ST_Intersection(a.geom,b.geom_3035) as geom from
  data.agri as a, 
  data.grc_bor as b;
```

you need to put the arguments as table aliases

Comment: The aliases don't matter. The query in the question only selects from agri table but grc_bor table is missing in the from part.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the entire SELECT clause in (...)

Comment: It's more elaborate than that. The link @mapperz gave me an answer. I'll update in a bit :)